# Can any one explain me the actual concept of Creating and Initialising an object in java?why a default constructor is used in initialising an object

Tags: java, oop

Can any one explain me the actual concept of Creating and Initialising an object in java?why a default constructor is used in initialising an object?
What is the need of a default constructor in initialising an object of a class??

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer, because you *don't* always use a default constructor. For example: `new File("foo")` doesn't use a default constructor. Please try to be specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one explain me the actual concept of Creating and Initialising an object in java?

It is not clear what you don't understand, perhaps you imagine there is more going on than there is.

Creating - creates an object

Initializing - gives the fields values.

> why a default constructor is used in initialising an object?

A default constructor is required to ensure all objects have a constructor even if you haven't written one.  Without this you couldn't create the object.

> What is the need of a default constructor in initialising an object of a class??

To ensure you create objects without having to write a trivial constructor (assuming this is fine)